# Linux 2.6.23 . Error In Receiving . Read function Returns -1

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

Please refer the Below code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <termios.h>

#define BAUDRATE    B115200
#define SER_DEVICE  "/dev/ttyS0"
#define FALSE       0
#define TRUE        1


int main()
{
int fd,c,res,i,n;
struct termios oldtio,newtio;
unsigned char buf[255] = "WELCOME TO THE WORLD OF LINUX PROGRAMMING\n";
unsigned char buf2[255]= {"\0"};
//Opening a Device for Reading Writing.
//O_NOCTTY : - The Port Never Becomes the Controlling Terminal of the Process.
//O_NDELAY : - Use NON-Blocking IO. on some system this also means Deactivating the DCD line.

fd=open("/dev/ttyS0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if(fd<0)
{
printf("\nError in opening the File\n");
exit(0);
}
else
{
printf("File Opened  SuccessFull..HurraYYY !!!!1\n");
}

//printf("--------------Test Begin---------------\n");

//Save Current Serial Port Settings

tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio);
//clear the struct for New port settings
memset(&newtio,0,sizeof(newtio));

//Baud rate : Set bps rate .
//You could also use cfsetispeed and cfsetospeed.
//CRTSCTS : Output Hardware Flow control
//CS8 : 8n1(8bit No Parity 1 Stopbit)
//CLOCAL : local connection no modem control
//CREAD : Enable Receiving character
//printf("Setting Configuration for Port");
newtio.c_cflag |= (BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD);

//IGNPAR : Ignore bytes with parity error.
//ICRNL : map CR to NL 
//printf("Setting Parity\n");
newtio.c_cflag |= (IGNPAR | ICRNL);

//RAW output
//printf("Raw Output\n");
newtio.c_oflag = 0;
//printf("Enabling Canonical format \n");
//ICANON : Enable canonical input.
newtio.c_lflag |= ICANON;
//printf("Initialising Char\n");
//Initialise all characters
newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;   /*Blocking read until one character arrives*/
newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;  /*Inter character timer unused*/

/*
Now clean the Modem Line and Activate the Settings for the Port.
*/
tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH);
printf("Flushing Lines\n");
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);


n=write(fd,&buf,42);
printf("n=%d",n);


for(i=0;i<sizeof(unsigned int);i++);

for(i=0;i<sizeof(unsigned int);i++);
for(i=0;i<sizeof(unsigned int);i++);
for(i=0;i<200;i++)
printf("");
n=0;
n = read(fd,&buf2,42);
if(n==-1)
{
printf("\nError in Receiving");
}
else
printf("Received String = %s",buf2);

/*
Restore the Old Port Setting
*/

tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);

printf("==============TEST END==============\n");

close(fd);
}
```

I am able to transmit the String which appears on the Hyperterminal. But the Function Read returns value as -1.
The Possibility i found is :
1. for Receiving the Configuration is Wrong.
2. Looping back is needed or not.

I tried Looping Back to but it does not Work.
i executed the Code in while(1)

> > transmit ans Receive ... and if read returns something != -1 ..break from the Loop. But that to doesn't work.
> >     What is the minimum delay that one should add in read/write cycle.

I am Executing this Code on MPC 8641d Processor.

Please Your Suggestion are important to me.

Hoping for your Guidence !!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

To know the detailed reason for read() failing, you need to see what value is stored in the global variable errno (this is documented in the man page for read).  An easy way to do that is to use `perror()` instead of printf() when you print the failure message--perror() will append a human-readable string that tells you the reason.

Comment: You need to `#include <errno.h>` to access errno directly.  `strerror(errno)` (C89) will give you a char pointer to the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Read John Zwinck's answer before this one ;)

For background info about errno: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Checking-for-Errors.html

To elaborate on the significance of the specific errno WRT read: not all "errors" mean "you've done something wrong" or "this connection cannot be read from".  They may mean simply that this connection cannot be read from at this instant, eg, if errno is EAGAIN on a non-blocking connection.

That means you will have to figure out what the error is, and if it is of that sort, how to deal with it.  Then you have to test against errno specifically, eg:

```
#include <errno.h>

int bytes = read(...);
if (bytes == -1) {
// example of an error which may happen under normal conditions
// for certain kinds of file descriptors:
    if (errno == EAGAIN) {
        // handle appropriately
    } else {
        // this is a real error which should not happen
    }
}
```

You can find the constants by printing the int value of errno and looking thru errno.h.  Chances are, they are actually in a file included by errno.h, such as /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h and errno-base.h.  Random example from the former on my system:

`#define ECOMM           70      /* Communication error on send */`

So perror() or strerror() would (probably) report "Communication error on send", but in any case, the int value of this is 70.  **Do not use that in your code**, they can vary across implementations; `#include <errno.h>` and use the constant `ECOMM`.